# java.lang.ClassCastException: casting an object, to his parent

Tags: java, android, layout, android-fragmentactivity

I'm a IOS coder, but I'm trying to learn a little bit of android, but I'm getting problems.

I have the following class:

```
package com.example.fragmenttabhostdemo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, the console says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.fragmenttabhostdemo.Tab1 cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong ? The problem I think, is occurring when I try to make the fragment activity for my android app layout, and add some tabs to the host:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

     tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Lengueta 1"), Tab1.class, null);
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Lengueta 2"),
                           Tab2.class, null);
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Lengueta 3"),
                           Tab3.class, null);
   }
```

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Any other ideas to get a tab layout easily, I just can't do it.

P.D.  I'm trying to follow this tutorial: 
http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-basico/32-unidad-2-diseno-de-la-interfaz-de-usuario-vistas-y-layouts/452-fragmenttabhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hint is this part right here:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

You're casting a regular `Fragment` to a support `Fragment`.  It's confusing because they are two classes with the same name, but located in different packages.  Essentially, if you're working with the support libraries, you should stick to all support types.  With that in mind, in your `Tab1` class, make the following change in your import statements.

```
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

Comment: Perfect answer dude, nice eyes!

Answer (score 2):

It says it can not be cast to a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. In you `Fragment` file, you have an import of `android.app.Fragment`. My guess is that your imports are off.

Comment: it's ok, but the upper one it's pretty most especific... : ) vote up too

Comment: No prob, that got posted while I was typing :)